# Android app to record events during the day and my reaction

Tags: android, note-taking

I want to monitor certain events which happen to me during the day, and be able to write down what I did when they occurred.

For each event, I would like to be able to 1) Select an event type from a list of types I have defined previously, 2) Select some kind of intensity on a scale, and 3) have the ability to make free-text notes (I have no pressing need for contents beyond text). The event should be recorded with a time stamp exact to at least a 5 minute interval; a duration would be quite nice too, but I probably can do without it.

I want also to record things I did (and have the program know that it is not the same thing as the events - in the worst case, it should let me have two different lists for "event type"). These reactions should also have a type I have predefined, and a field for free text notes. Ideally, I will also be able to give an evaluation of the reaction's success, again on a numerical scale.

Beyond these must-haves, it would be nice to be able to attach a few descriptive tags to the whole day.

To give an example, imagine following use case: I am on a diet. I want to record an event of type "Hunger" at 10:15 AM, with the intensity 2 of 5, leaving the note field empty. And then record the reaction of type "Snack", with the textual note "a banana" at 10:20 AM, with the reaction success "5 of 5" because I wasn't hungry after the banana.

The application should be able to export the data so I can evaluate them. CSV would be ideal, but any flexible format is OK. Proprietary or binary formats are not sufficient.

As the events I want to record happen throughout the day, I want to be able to record them on the one device I am most likely to have with me, which is my Android 4.4.2 phone.

I want to document the entries with as little disturbance to my routine as possible, so an efficient entry process is important. The list definition is pretty stable, its user friendliness is of lower priority.

---

Note: I'm not on a diet, that was just an example. So please don't suggest diet-specific applications, I know these exist. What I need is an application in which I can completely freely define the types of event and reaction.

Generic diaries with text-only entries are not sufficient for my purposes, I need the ability to differentiate between the types of event and reaction.

If you don't know of an app which fits these very specific criteria, I'd be happy if you could point me to something which is at least similar. I have no idea what terms to look for in the app store to see if there is something good enough for my purposes.